Getting ClassCastException while creating EJB objects in EJB 3.0
As a part of JDK 17 migration, we had upgraded from EJb 2.1 to EJB 3.0. Deployment is successful in Wildfly 27, but I'm getting the below  ClassCastException.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.****.CacheManagerWrapperBean$$$view7 cannot be cast to class jakarta.ejb.EJBHome
In my code I'm trying to create the EJB object and casting into CacheManagerWrapperBean which is my interface class.
Previously, in EJb 2.1  it was been casted into Home class, now in EJB 3.0 since the Home class is not required , I'm casting it into interface class.
I'm still using ejb-jar.xml and not annotations. In ejb-jar.xml I have commented the remote and home classes. I ahve only the interface and bean class details.
How to resolve this?
